# Split string and number columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a table such as

```
ItemID        ClassID
------------------------
1             10, 13, 12
2             5, 7
```

and would like to copy the data to another table like so

```
ItemID     Numbering       ClassID
----------------------------------
1          1               10
1          2               13
1          3               12
2          1               5
2          2               7
```

1. Separating the comma-delimited `ClassID` field into individual rows, retaining the order they had in the first table
2. Populating the `Numbering` row on insert. The `Numbering` column has sequential integers for each batch of `ClassID` and is why `ClassID` needs to be kept in order.

I have attempted this with the following function:

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
   (
      @String NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )
  RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE(
   Value INT
  )
 AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @SplitLength INT
  DECLARE @Delimiter VARCHAR(10) 
  SET @Delimiter = ','

  WHILE len(@String) > 0
   BEGIN
    SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE charindex(@Delimiter, @String)
         WHEN 0 THEN
           datalength(@String) / 2
         ELSE
           charindex(@Delimiter, @String) - 1
       END)

   INSERT INTO @SplittedValues
   SELECT cast(substring(@String, 1, @SplitLength) AS INTEGER)
   WHERE
   ltrim(rtrim(isnull(substring(@String, 1, @SplitLength), ''))) <> '';

   SELECT @String = (CASE ((datalength(@String) / 2) - @SplitLength)
         WHEN 0 THEN
           ''
         ELSE
           right(@String, (datalength(@String) / 2) - @SplitLength - 1)
       END)

  END

 RETURN

END
```

but it only partly works. It copies the rows the correct amount of times (i.e. three times for `ItemID=1`, and twice for `ItemID=2` in the above example), but they are exact copies of the row (all saying '10, 13, 12') and the comma-delimited parts are not split up. There is also nothing in the function to add to the `Numbering` column.

So, I have two questions: How do I modify the above function to split up the `ClassID` string, and what do I add to correctly increment the `Numbering` column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a recursive CTE to do it.

```
WITH SplitCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        itemid,
        LEFT(ClassID,CHARINDEX(',',ClassID)-1) AS ClassID
        ,RIGHT(ClassID,LEN(ClassID)-CHARINDEX(',',ClassID)) AS remaining
        FROM table1
        WHERE ClassID IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',ClassID)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        itemid,
        LEFT(remaining,CHARINDEX(',',remaining)-1)
        ,RIGHT(remaining,LEN(remaining)-CHARINDEX(',',remaining))
        FROM SplitCTE
        WHERE remaining IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',remaining)>0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        itemid,remaining,null
        FROM SplitCTE
        WHERE remaining IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',remaining)=0

)
SELECT 
 itemid,
 row_number() over (partition by itemid order by cast(classid as int) asc) as Numbering,
 cast (ClassID  as int) as ClassID
FROM 
 SplitCTE 

 UNION ALL
 select 
 ItemId,
 1,
 cast(classid as int)
 FROM table1
 WHERE ClassID IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(',',ClassID) = 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08ea6/1)

Comment: It works mostly! There's one problem, some columns with `Numbering=1` have a blank `ClassID`. Some columns end with a comma, i.e. `10, 13, 12,` is that what's affecting it? Also, will this still work if `ClassID` has more than 3 entries?

Comment: I solved this issue by writing a CTE that goes before yours and removes the trailing comma if it is present, and a CTE after it that removes the blank row. Feels a bit cumbersome, but it works as intended now.

Comment: If the string ends in a comma, and you're casting everything to an INT, you'll end up with a 0, not a null.  I added an example of that, and to make sure it handles rows where there's only 1 entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE( ID INT IDENTITY, data VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @t(data) SELECT '10, 13, 12'
INSERT INTO @t(data) SELECT '5, 7'
```

select F1.id,O.splitdata, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
from ( 
        select *,cast(''+replace(F.data,',','')+'' as XML) as xmlfilter from @t F
    )F1
cross apply 
( 
    select fdata.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as splitdata  from f1.xmlfilter.nodes('X') as fdata(D)
) O